# Cómo combinar dos arrays para armar un listado?

Tags: php, array

Tengo un arreglo con películas y su actor protagónico. Y en OTRO arreglo tengo las películas y sus año de estreno.

Tomando datos de ambos arreglos, quisiera mostrar cada película con su actor protagónico y su año de estreno.

Por ejemplo:

```
Rápidos y Furiosos 8 -- actor: Vin disel -- Estreno: 2017
Star Trek: Into Darkness -- actor: Chris pine -- Estreno: 2013
Los vengadores 3 -- actor: Robert Downey Jr. -- Estreno: 2018
```

Lo planteé de esta manera pero me lo muestra 9 veces.

```
<?php

$arreglo1 = array(
  'Rapido y Furioso 8' => 'actor: Vin Disel',
  'Star Trek: Into Darkness' => 'actor: Chris Pine',
  'Los Vengadores 3' => 'actor: Robert Downey Jr.'
);

$arreglo2 = array(
  'Rapido y Furioso 8' => 'Estreno: 2017',
  'Star Trek: Into Darkness' => 'Estreno: 2013',
  'Los Vengadores 3' => 'Estreno: 2018');


  foreach ( $arreglo1 as $pelicula => $actor ){
    foreach ( $arreglo2 as $pelicula => $estreno ){
      echo( $pelicula . " --- " . $actor . " --- " . $estreno . "<br>" );
    }
  }
```

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Buenas. Siguiendo programación orientada a objetos, lo mejor es definir una clase llamada película, que contenga un miembro por cada elemento que quieras almacenar (título, protagonista...), y tener un array de películas que recorrer. http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.php Un saludo,

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tienes un error de logica:

Se te repite todo 9 veces, porque lo que estas haciendo es recorrer un for de 3 elementos, y para cada uno de esos 3 elementos, imprimir los valores de otro array de 3 elementos (3*3 = 9)

```
foreach ($arreglo1 as $pelicula => $actor) {

        foreach ($arreglo2 as $pelicula => $estreno) {
            echo($pelicula." --- ".$actor." --- ".$estreno."<br>");
        }
}
```

En realidad lo que quiere hacer, como no especificaste que realmente quieres hacer, y parece un ejercicio de tarea, es imprimir el valor de los dos array, utilizando los mismos indices.. entonces como ejemplo digamos que podriamos hacer algo asi:

```
foreach($arreglo1 as $pelicula => $actor)
{
   echo ($pelicula." --- " .$actor. " --- " .$arreglo2[$pelicula];
}
```

Donde por cada pelicula del arreglo1, busco en el arreglo2 asociativo dos, la misma.

Comment: Perfecto me sirvió, muchas gracias gbianchi.

Comment: Miguel si te sirvio alguna respuesta por favor aceptala para q futuros usuarios sepan que respuestan sirven y cuales no. Mira como funciona el sitio si no lo hiciste.

Answer (score 2):

Otra alternativa seria crear un array multidimensional. Y hacer el recorrido de esta forma.

```
<?php

$arreglos = array(
 array('pelicula' => 'Rapido y Furioso 8', 'actor' => 'Vin Disel', 'estreno' => 2017),
 array('pelicula' => 'Star Trek: Into Darkness', 'actor' => 'Chris Pine', 'estreno' =>2013),
 array('pelicula' => 'Los Vengadores 3', 'actor'=> 'Robert Downey Jr.', 'estreno' => 2018),
);


print_r($arreglos);

echo "<br>"; // salto de lina
for ($i=0; $i < count($arreglos); $i++){
  echo "<br>"; // salto de lina
  echo $arreglos[$i]['pelicula'] .  " --- actor: " .
  $arreglos[$i]['actor'] .  " --- estreno: " .
  $arreglos[$i]['estreno'] ;
}
```